# Write tuple to csv by skipping missing columns

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a list of ordered tuples which each tuple contains column name and value pair to be written to  a csv for example

lst = [('name','bob'),('age',19),('loc','LA')]

which has in for for bob, age 19 and location, loc, in LA. I want to be able to write this to CSV file based on column names and sometimes some of these columns are missing, for example for another row.

lst2 = [('name','bob'),('loc','LA')]
age is missing, how I can write these rows properly in python to  a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tuples can be used to initialize a `dict` so `csv.DictWriter` seems the best choice. In this example I create a `dict` filled with default values. For each list of tuples, I copy the dict, update with the known values and write it out.

```
import csv

# sample data
lst = [('name','bob'),('age',19),('loc','LA')]
lst2 = [('name','jane'),('loc','LA')]
lists = [lst, lst2]

# columns need some sort of default... I just guessed
defaults = {'name':'', 'age':-1, 'loc':'N/A'}

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=sorted(defaults.keys()))
    writer.writeheader()
    for row_tuples in lists:
        # copy defaults then update with known values
        kv = defaults.copy()
        kv.update(row_tuples)
        writer.writerow(kv)

# debug...
print open('output.csv').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give more examples, as to what exactly is required- as what if the location is not given in `ls2` then what do you want to write to your csv? From what I understand, you can make a function and default argument:

```
import csv
def write_tuples_to_csv(name="DefaultName", age="DefaultAge", loc="Default location"):
     writer = csv.writer(open("/path/to/csv/file", 'a')) # appending to a file
     row = (name, age, loc)
     writer.writerow(['name','num','location'])
     writer.writerow(row)
```

Now you can call this function for every item in the list. This should help you to get you started.